# How to call a function inside another function?

Tags: python, function

Im new to the community and coding in general, chose python as my first language and finished a couple of online courses.

I am trying to work on a project to practice and keep improving, Its a credit card number validator, checks the digits, prefix and checksum, but Im getting stuck at a very basic concept.

I m defining a function as an input for the user the enter de credit card number, then Id like to call the function inside another one that validates the prefix and the check sum, but I keep getting a traceback as if my variable is not defined.

```
# User inputs the cc number
def inp_cc():
    cc_number = input("Insert credit card number: ")
    return cc_number

# This will validate the prefix and lenght and print it if its correct, 
otherwise will show an error
# Code is not completed as I keep getting the traceback

def val_tc():
    inp_cc()
    if len(cc_number) == 13 or len(cc_number) == 16:
        cc_brand = "Visa"
        print("Credit card number: %s" % cc_number,"Credit card brand: %s" % cc_brand)
    else:
        quit()

# Here I call the val_tc() function that should also call the inp_cc()

val_tc()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    val_tc()
  File "main.py", line 11, in val_tc
    if len(cc_number) == 13 or len(cc_number) == 16:
NameError: name 'cc_number' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `inp_cc()` to `cc_number = inp_cc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you didn't actually assign the return value of the `inp_cc` function to anything. Here's a fixed version:

```
def inp_cc():
    cc_number = input("Insert credit card number: ")
    return cc_number



def val_tc():
    cc_number = inp_cc()  # FIXED
    if len(cc_number) == 13 or len(cc_number) == 16:
        cc_brand = "Visa"
        print("Credit card number: %s" % cc_number,"Credit card brand: %s" % cc_brand)
    else:
        quit()


val_tc()
```

Comment: I understand, I thought the program will execute the val_tc() function and return the variable´s value so the next line will execute considering it. Means I always have to assign it in every function I use or define it as global variable right? or might as well just copy all the code in one function (val_tc()).

Comment: Global variables are hardly every a good idea. In this case the best way would probably just be to merge the two functions into one.

Comment: Alright that makes it clear, thanks a lot for the replies and sorry for the mistakes when posting the question, literally my first project ever with a programming language. Have a good day!

Comment: Don't worry, this post was still 10x better than most first posts by users. Glad I could help, have a nice day too!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call inp_cc, not int_cc.
I think it is just mistype.

Comment: Yeah, just pasted the right error message. Sorry about that.